# Expression and Looping process

Tags: tcl

I have some problem and hope anyone can solve my problem as belows;

1. First question; Maths

   ```
   set a 3
   puts [format "%.3f" [expr ($a+2)/2]]
   ```

   Why the output is still `2.000`?
2. Second question; How to stop/break for incr "Third Looping" process and continue "First Looping" process

   ```
   for {set numA 0} {$numA < 5} {incr numA} {      ;#First Looping process
     for {set numB 0} {$numB < $oneNum} {incr numB} {  ;#Second Looping process
       for {set numC 0} {$numC < $twoNum} {incr numC} {    ;#Third Looping process
         if {$dataA == $dataB} {
           #How to stop incr "Third Looping" process and continue "First Looping" incr process
         }
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, the `expr` does not know that the result it produces is being given to a command that wants a floating point number, so it is using integer division as both operands are integers.

We can do the whole thing in several steps without changing anything:

```
set a 3
set b [expr ($a+2)/2]
puts "b=$b"
puts [format "%.3f" $b]
```

I've printed the intermediate value out as well, so that you can see that `($a+2)/2` is `2`; Tcl's integer division rounds down. Given that that is true, small wonder that the `format` renders the value as `2.000`.

---

For the second question, Tcl doesn't support multi-level `break`. It doesn't come up as a problem very often though, and most of the cases where it would can be handled by the strategic use of helper procedures.

In more detail, you can use `break` to stop the current inner-most loop, but only that inner-most loop. The `Second Looping process` between won't be stopped by a `break` in the inner-most nesting level. The simplest mechanism for dealing with this directly is a custom exception code, but that's hardly simple:

```
set MyException 123;  # Small integer greater than 5
for {set numA 0} {$numA < 5} {incr numA} {                   #First Looping process
    for {set numB 0} {$numB < $oneNum} {incr numB} {         #Second Looping process
        try {
            for {set numC 0} {$numC < $twoNum} {incr numC} { #Third Looping process
                if {$dataA == $dataB} {
                    return -level 0 -code $MyException
                }
            }
        } on $MyException {} {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

You could avoid the deeply tricky custom exception code by instead using a flag variable:

```
for {set numA 0} {$numA < 5} {incr numA} {               #First Looping process
    for {set numB 0} {$numB < $oneNum} {incr numB} {     #Second Looping process
        set foundIt false
        for {set numC 0} {$numC < $twoNum} {incr numC} { #Third Looping process
            if {$dataA == $dataB} {
                # Set the flag to indicate we've found our matching case
                set foundIt true
                # Terminate the inner loop
                break
            }
        }
        if {$foundIt} {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This is pretty ugly (especially when the logic gets more complex), but works. Fortunately, it doesn't come up very often. More frequently, one splits the code like this:

```
proc innerSearch {numA} {
    global oneNum twoNum
    for {set numB 0} {$numB < $oneNum} {incr numB} {     #Second Looping process
        for {set numC 0} {$numC < $twoNum} {incr numC} { #Third Looping process
            if {$dataA == $dataB} {
                # Stop the Second Looping by returning from the procedure
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

for {set numA 0} {$numA < 5} {incr numA} {               #First Looping process
    innerSearch $numA
}
```

This tends to make a lot more sense in practice, where more mnemonic names would be used.

Comment: Thanks, so I am still dont understand. Would you like to display me the an example please.

Answer (score 1):

The output of arithmatic operator "/" depends on the type of data it is being applied upon. You have integer values and so the output is integer. You can covert one of the value to float first as below

```
puts [format "%.3f" [expr ($a+2)/double(2)]]
2.500
```

For second question, **continue** command will stop third loop and go to first one

```
for {set numA 0} {$numA < 5} {incr numA} {      ;#First Looping process
  for {set numB 0} {$numB < $oneNum} {incr numB} {  ;#Second Looping process
    for {set numC 0} {$numC < $twoNum} {incr numC} {    ;#Third Looping process
      if {$dataA == $dataB} {
        continue
      }
    }
  }
}
```